# jQuery replace shows up in logs/alert but not in actual content?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

This seems weird, but doing a jQuery `replace()` seems to only work when it's run in `alert()` or `console.log`.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
$('.settings_item[data-slide-id=1324] .answers_fields_template li').each(function(index) {
  var regexp = new RegExp('new_answers', 'g');
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  $(this).html().replace(regexp, new_id);
});
```

And here's the html code:

```
<li data-weight="1">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_skeleton" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][skeleton]" type="hidden" value="true">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_text" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][text]" size="30" type="text" value="Great!">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_weight" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][weight]" type="hidden" value="3">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_response_class" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][response_class]" type="hidden" value="rate">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_id" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][id]" type="hidden">
</li>
<li data-weight="2">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_skeleton" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][skeleton]" type="hidden" value="true">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_text" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][text]" size="30" type="text" value="OK">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_weight" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][weight]" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_response_class" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][response_class]" type="hidden" value="rate">
    <input id="survey_questions_attributes_0_answers_attributes_new_answers_id" name="survey[questions_attributes][0][answers_attributes][new_answers][id]" type="hidden">
</li>
```

I'm trying to replace all instances of `new_answers` with the contents of the `new_id` variable.

When I run that, nothing gets replace. But, if I wrap `$(this).html().replace(regexp, new_id);` in `alert()` or `console.log()`, then the output of those shows `new_answers` being replaced as it should.

I can't figure out why on earth that'd be the case and now my brain hurts.

Comment: Is that just a quick-pasted code sample with accidental duplication or do you have all those duplicate IDs and NAMEs on your multiple inputs? If so, that will eventually cause you more headaches.

Comment: @RwL: That might have been me not reading things properly when editing. I see it's been rolled back and edited properly by the OP. Apologies to all.

Comment: Weird, I still see the duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `replace`d HTML back to the element. Try this line:

`$(this).html($(this).html().replace(regexp, new_id));`

James

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do a `.replaceWith()`? I do not see `.replace()` in the jquery API.

Comment: the `.html()` would return a string.  `.replace()` is a method on the native string object...

Answer (score 0):

```
var newHtml = $(this).html().replace(regexp, new_id);
$(this).html(newHtml);
```